# Cakephp 3 can't connect to the application

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing a web application with cakephp 3 and I wanted to create users that can authenticate. I followed the blog tuto on the book and all went good : I can add a user, it updates the data base and I can find the users/login page but from there I can't connect even though I'm using the correct username/password ...

There's my controller's login function :

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error(__("Incorrect username or password."));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Mmh, I didnt check as well as I thought... I jsut had to hash my passwords creatin an entity User and adding this :

```
    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
```

Now it works :)